# ANGULAR JS and React

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I am very new to Angular Js and I am having some difficulties with my web application.
So I have a .state to load a page for my website. I am trying to load a .js file that is written in REACT and I tried including the path for the .js file in the "templateUrl" component but it does not work. I only get the REACT code written in the browser. I also have a CSS file to be included as well.

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you show what you're doing?

Comment: .state("app.FAQ", {
        url: "/FAQ",
        templateUrl: "views/FAQ/index.js " 
    })

Comment: include relevant code in your post and format it

Comment: Please consult the [help] articles, especially "[ask]" and on providing a [mcve]. See also "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)".

Answer (score 0):

I think,

the best thing is this make a directive in react js and load that directive in angularjs templates.